# I recently flew from Bar Harbor Maine to Boston Logan airport on a Cessna 402 turbo prop airplane. We didn’t have a copilot is this a FAA violation?

Tags: safety

I flew from bar harbor Maine to Boston MA on a Cessna 402 turboprop with one pilot is this a FAA violation?

Comment: I cannot find a definitive citation for this specific aircraft, but very likely no.  Many aircraft of this size are certified to operate with a single pilot.

Comment: A Cessna 402 does not require a co- pilot, in and of itself. However,  depending on the type of operation being conducted and some other factors (such as weather, airplane equipment, etc.) it may require a co-pilot for a particular flight. Was this a flight for which you bought a ticket?  Did the operator of this flight advertise its services? By the way, a Cessna 402 has reciprocating engines and is not a "turboprop (not really relevant to your question,  just an FYI).

Comment: A Cessna 402 is a turbocharged reciprocating twin engined airplane, maybe this is what the OP meant.

Answer (score 5):

The Cessna 402 is a single pilot commuter airplane. It has two sets of controls, but the second pilot seat can even be used as an extra passenger seat.

It is not a turboprop, it's a piston engine airplane, with MTOW less than 12,500 lbs. As such, it can be operated by one pilot with a multi-engine land endorsement, depending on how.

Not always though. As 757toga mentioned, under Part 135 IFR, it would require two pilots.

Comment: Operating Part 135 IFR would require two pilots unless the aircraft was equipped with an approved autopilot and it was authorized to be used.  This is frequently the case (buying an autopilot is less expensive than paying for two pilots).